# h1 tag only display in hostinger

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <title>DaDevCoder</title>
        <link href="{{ asset('/resources/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="{{ asset('/node_modules/toastr/toastr.scss') }}" rel="stylesheet">



        @viteReactRefresh
        @vite('resources/js/app.jsx')

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="" id="app">
            <h1>asdassdasdasasd</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just got this problem my react file won't load in id 'app' only h1 tag displays in hostinger, maybe file directories are some adjustments maybe, Ineed your help

why only h1 tag only appears in welcome.blade.php file, what are the adjustment I need in my file, btw I upload the file in hostinger

Comment: You need to share your React code too, at least a related part of it.

Comment: Show us what you have in `app.jsx`..  didn't you mean `app.js` instead ?

Comment: Vite uses .jsx.

Comment: The names are case sensitive.  Unless you've changed something, it should be "App.jsx" and "App.css".